# How to reduce first load js size on Next js?

Tags: next.js

On my next js project, first load js size of the pages where I use char.js is more than 2 Mb. Even though I tried dynamic import, it is not reducing. Is there another way to fix this?

```
import { createResponseSpectraData } from 'lib/apps/gmp_prediction/draw_graph';
import { generateSpectralAccelerations } from 'lib/apps/gmp_prediction/generate_files';
import * as types from 'lib/apps/gmp_prediction/types';
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import * as btn from 'components/elements/Buttton';

export default function ResponseSpectra({
    output,
}: {
    output: types.OutputData;
}) {
    const saCanvas = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);
    const periods = output.periods;
    const spectralAccelerations = output.spectral_accelerations;

    useEffect(() => {
        const loadChart = async () => {
            const { default: Chart } = await import('chart.js/auto');
            const { getSpectraGraphConfig } = await import(
                'lib/apps/graph_configs'
            );
            const graphData = createResponseSpectraData(
                periods as number[],
                spectralAccelerations as number[],
            );
            const config = getSpectraGraphConfig(
                graphData,
                'Periyod (s)',
                'Spektral İvme(g)',
            );
            if (!saCanvas.current) return;
            const ctx = saCanvas.current.getContext('2d');
            if (!ctx) return;
            const saChart = new Chart(ctx, config);

            return () => {
                saChart.destroy();
            };
        };

        loadChart();
    }, [periods, spectralAccelerations]);

    return (
        <>
            <span>
                <btn.DownloadExcelButton
                    onClick={() => generateSpectralAccelerations(output)}
                >
                    Tepki Spektrumlarını İndir
                </btn.DownloadExcelButton>
            </span>
            <div className="h-96">
                <canvas id="paChart" ref={saCanvas} />
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

I was expecting a first load js size between 150-200 kb.